# Python Snowflake connector not able to connect on Azure VM

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am trying to connect to SnowFlake from an Azure VM. I made a simple class method that looks like below:

```py
class SQLClient():
  def __init__(self, user, password, account):
    super().__init__()
    self.conn = None
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    self.account = account
    self.open_connection()

  def open_connection(self):
    if not self.conn:
      log.info(f'Opening DB connection.')
      self.conn = snowflake.connector.connect(user=self.user, password=self.password, account=self.account)
```

However the connector keeps logging the below message.

`This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.`

It keeps displaying the message over and over aging.
Anyone ever faced this issue?

Comment: You are probably failing the [OCSP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#ocsp) check. Run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/hostname-whitelist.html) if possible and you will get more details.

Comment: This message is typically a warning, not a failure.  Is your connection really not being made?